# Java Program TextFile Issue

Tags: javascript

I have a program where a text file is read in and then each word in the file is outputted, followed by the # of times it is repeated throughout the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code.

```
import java.io.*;

class FileRead {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        // Open the file that is the first 
        // command line parameter
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\formate.txt");
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Print the content on the console
            System.out.println(strLine);
        }
        //Close the input stream
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't use a BufferedReader in the file. It's something in my while loop I believe. It's reading line by line rather than reading the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
{
    File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
    File outputFile = new File("output.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
    HashMap<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    while (scanner.hasNext())
    {
        String word = scanner.next();
        if (count.containsKey(word))
        {
            count.put(word, count.get(word) + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            count.put(word, 1);
        }
    }
    scanner.close();

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : count.entrySet())
    {
        writer.write("#" + entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue()+"\r\n");
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Can't use a buffered reader or HashMap :(. I know it would be way easier that way but it's an assignment.

Comment: This code don't use BufferedReader, it only use BufferedWriter, The only problem then is the HashMap. The Scanner class is ideal, your can use it and it reads word by word

Answer (score 0):

This also, it is a lot simpler if You can't use HashMap or BufferedReader:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordCounter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
    {
        File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
        File outputFile = new File("output.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
        LinkedList<Word> words = new LinkedList<Word>();

        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
            String word = scanner.next();
            addWord(words, word);
        }
        scanner.close();

        WriteToFile(outputFile, words);
    }

    private static void WriteToFile(File outputFile, LinkedList<Word> words) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
        for (Word word : words)
        {
            writer.write("#" + word.getWord() + " " + word.getCount() + "\r\n");
        }
        writer.close();
    }

    private static void addWord(LinkedList<Word> words, String word)
    {
        for (Word aWord : words)
        {
            if (aWord.getWord().equals(word))
            {
                aWord.incrementCount();
                return;
            }
        }
        words.add(new Word(word, 1));
    }
}

class Word
{
    private String word;
    private int count;

    public Word(String word, int count)
    {
        this.word = word;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getWord()
    {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word)
    {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count)
    {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void incrementCount()
    {
        count++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Word: " + word + " Count: " + count;

    }

}
```